# MIPS n64 base+offset addressing in a TableGen pattern

Tags: llvm, mips

I am trying to create a tablegen pattern that matches an add + load with some special wrapper instruction and replaces them with an LW $r1, offset($r2).

Here is a sample of what I was able to do:

```
MipsPat<(i64 (extloadi32 (add GPR64:$hi, (MyWrapper addr:$lo)))), 
        (LW64 GPR64, [base=GPR64:$hi, offset=addr:$lo]);
```

Obviously the part in square brackets is the one that I am missing.
I have tried for a couple of days to find a way to express the base+offset addressing in tablegen to no avail. At this point I am wondering if the tablegen files are the correct place to do this kind of operation.

This is what I am trying to understand:

- How can I make a base+offset memory operand for the LW instruction in the td file? (if possible)
- Is the td file the right place to do this kind of optimization?

Any help is appreciated.

### For the curious

I am actually trying to implement HIGHEST/HIGHER static relocations for the MIPS n64 backend and I am stuck at trying to optimize this:

```
lui $4, %highest(glob_ext)
daddiu  $4, $4, %higher(glob_ext)
dsll    $4, $4, 16
daddiu  $4, $4, %hi(glob_ext)
dsll    $4, $4, 16
daddiu  $4, $4, %lo(glob_ext)
lw      $2, 0($4)
```

Into this:

```
lui $4, %highest(glob_ext)
daddiu  $4, $4, %higher(glob_ext)
dsll    $4, $4, 16
daddiu  $4, $4, %hi(glob_ext)
dsll    $4, $4, 16
lw      $4,%lo(glob_ext)($4)
```